# /.. Not working in PHP

Tags: php

For requiring files in my PHP scripts I am using the following code :

```
require(dirname(__FILE__)."/../config.php");
```

with the config.php file being located a level higher than the file requiring it. However this appears to not work and the file cannot be located, with the following error :

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home3/**myusername**/public_html/PHP/access/login.php on line 3
```

I'm not sure what the error is as I have looked online and this appears to be the way others have done it. I believe however that the /.. is not causing it to go up a level.

**EDIT 1**

I changed the code to

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/PHP/config.php");
```

and still receive the same error.

**EDIT 2**

The reason I am using an absolute path is because I have been led to believe this will work no matter where I call the file from, i.e if a file in a different directory includes this file (for this particular file it wont be the case but it will be in other files where I will use this) it will still include the config.php file correctly and not relative to the path of the file that included login.php.

**EDIT 3**

if I vardump the require path it prints the following :

```
string(52) "/home3/*myusername*/public_html/PHP/access/../config.php"
```

so obviously not going to the right location.

**EDIT 4**

Absolute path of file being required

```
/home3/*myusername*/public_html/PHP/config.php
```

Absolute path of file requiring it

```
/home3/*myusername*/public_html/PHP/access/login.php
```

Comment: remove the 1st `/` so that your absolute path becomes a relative path and Bob should be your uncle.

Comment: `var_dump(dirname(__FILE__)."/../config.php");` and see what path is actually generated

Comment: "I changed the code to" --- do you **understand** what it does or just randomly copy advices and expect one of them will magically work?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was actually an error in my copying and pasting I shall change the edit to what I actually tried, my mistake.

Comment: @JoshJackson can you provide the absolute path of file required it and the absolute path of the config.php?

Answer (score 0):

try providing relative path to root. This is a better approach then providing relative to current file.

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/config.php");
```

Comment: Why do you think the `config.php` is in the document root?

Comment: I'm not sure , but i suggest to provide path from root, its a clearer way of providing path.

Comment: the clear way is to rely on your project root, not on some environment variable

Comment: My config actually isn't in my document root, it is located in a sub folder named PHP.

Comment: @Josh Jackson: if it is not - why did you even try this proposal?

Comment: @zerkms Agreed. I'm not sure about the method to get project root. If you know , kindly edit my answer for better use. Thanks

Comment: @JoshJackson then try require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/PHP/config.php");

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan: you define the project root by *yourself*. Just `define('MY_PROJECT_ROOT', '/path/to/project');`

Answer (score -3):

Remove the first / - `"../config.php"`

Comment: What would it change?

Comment: Try it - I have exactly the same code and files arranged exactly the same way.

Comment: please read the OPs question once again `require(dirname(__FILE__)."/../config.php");`